# How do I access the input element created by data-filter="true"

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

G'day all. I have a form, part of which is a search box using jquery mobile's listview autocomplete/data-filter using local data.

After the user enters a couple of characters, they may select one of the suggested results from the autocomplete. When this happens, I wish to fill in the search box with the selected result.

Problem is, that since jquery-mobile creates the input element, I'm unsure how to get a handle to the element.

I need to have a handle to the element because I'd like in some cases to have a default value, and because I'm not using the listview items as links (it's part of a form.)

The examples I've found seem only to show how to set the listview filter up, but not actually do anything with it once the results are presented.

my listview:
http://jsfiddle.net/EXHNp/

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<ul class="emp_listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Emp Code..." data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li><a>fred</a></li>
     <li><a>mary</a></li>
     <li><a>bob</a></li>
     <li><a>alex</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to access the input element, instead you will need to traverse the DOM.
You can use the following code to get the input element.

```
$("ul.emp_listview").prev().find('input.ui-input-text');
```

Comment: Thanks, I kind of used this but just .find()'d the element from within the widget.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up extending the mobile.listview widget to add get/set functionality

Essentially what I did:

```
$.mobile.listview.prototype.searchElement;

$.mobile.listview.prototype.getInput = function(){
    return $(searchElement).find('input').val();    
};

$.mobile.listview.prototype.setInput = function(a_input){  
    return $(searchElement).find('input').val(a_input);
};
```

And I've overridden the delegated listviewcreate function to save the created input wrapper in the object.

```
$.mobile.document.delegate( "ul, ol", "listviewcreate", function() {
...
searchElement = wrapper;
```

Quite possibly the very wrong way, but seems to work. Critique welcome.